# Count amount of relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have an eloquent model User which is in 1:N relation with itself (a single user can refer multiple users, and a single user can be referred by a single user only).

```
/*
 * Get the user's referrals
 */

public function referrals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

/*
 * Get the referred user's parent referral
 */

public function parentReferral()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Does Laravel provide a native method that will count all the belongsToMany relations?

(A simple way I can do this is just get the parent user's id and manually count all the appearances, but I wish to know if there's a method given by Laravel that I can use on the object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method to count the number of results from a relationship:

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models

```
User::withCount('referrals')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, search myself but couldn't find it in the documentation for some reason :)